# Is reading a CSV file from S3 into a Spark dataframe expected to be so slow?

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3

I am building an application that needs to load data sets from S3.  The functionality is working correctly, but the performance is surprisingly slow.

The datasets are in CSV format.  There are approximately 7M records (lines) in each file, and each file is 600-700MB.

```
val spark = SparkSession
       .builder()
       .appName("MyApp")
       .getOrCreate()

val df = spark
     .read
    .option("header", "true") 
    .option("inferSchema", "true") 
    .csv(inFileName:_*)
    // inFileName is a list that current contains 2 file names
    // eg.  s3://mybucket/myfile1.csv

val r = df.rdd.flatMap{ row =>
      /*
       * Discard poorly formated input records 
       */
      try {
        totalRecords.add(1)

        // this extracts several columns from the dataset
        // each tuple of indexColProc specifies the index of the column to
        // select from the input row, and a function to convert
        // the value to an Int
        val coords = indexColProc.map{ case (idx, func) => func( row.get(idx).toString ) }

        List( (coords(0), coords) )
      }
      catch {
        case e: Exception => {    
          badRecords.add(1)
          List()
        }
      }
    }

println("Done, row count " + r.count )
```

I ran this on an AWS cluster of 5 machines, each an m3.xlarge.  The maximizeResourceAllocation parameter was set to true, and this was the only application running on the cluster.

I ran the application in twice.  The first time with 'inFileName' pointing at the files on S3, and the second time pointing at a local copy of the files in hadoop file system.

When I look at the Spark history server and drill down to the job that corresponds to the final r.count action, I see that it takes 2.5 minutes when accessing the files on s3, and 18s when accessing the files locally on hdfs.  I"ve gotten proportionally similar results when I run the same experiment on a smaller cluster or in master=local configuration.

When I copy the s3 files to the cluster using

```
aws s3 cp <file>
```

It only takes 6.5s to move one 600-700MB file.  So it doesn't seem the raw I/O of the machine instance is contributing that much to the slow down.

Is this kind of slow performance when accessing s3 expected?  If not, could someone please point out where I'm going wrong.  If it is expected, are other ways to do this that would have better performance?  Or do I need to develop something to simply copy the files over from s3 to hdfs before the application runs?

Comment: maybe try `df.cache()` before you run the `flatMap`/

Comment: I did try that, but it either had no effect or actually caused the pipeline to hang (I was on a different machine instance when I tried that experiment).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some more digging I discovered that using S3 native makes a huge difference. I just changed the URI prefix to s3n:// and the performance for the job in question went from 2.5 minutes down to 21s. So only a 3s penalty for accessing s3 vs hdfs, which is pretty reasonable.

When searching for this topic there are many posts that mention s3n has a max file size limit of 5GB.  However, I came across [this](https://notes.mindprince.in/2014/08/01/difference-between-s3-block-and-s3-native-filesystem-on-hadoop.html) which says that max files size limit was increased to 5TB in Hadoop 2.4.0.

"Using the S3 block file system is no longer recommended."

Answer (score 1):

We faced the exact same issue about a couple of months ago, except that our data was 1TB so the issue was more pronounced.

We dug into it and finally came to the following conclusion:
Since we had 5 instances with 30 executors each, every time a stage was scheduled (and the first thing the task would do is fetch data from S3), so these tasks will be bottle-necked on network bandwidht, then they all move to compute part of the task and may contend for CPU simultaneously.

So basically because the tasks are all doing the same thing at the same time, they are always contending for the same resources.

We figured out that allowing only `k` number of tasks at any point would allow them to finish download quickly and move to the compute part and next set of `k` tasks can then come in and start downloading. This way, now `k` (as opposed to all) tasks are getting full bandwidth and some tasks are simultaneously doing something useful on CPU or I/O without waiting for each other on some common resource.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sounds worth a try.  Could you provide some pointers on how to implement that kind of granular control of the task execution?  In my case there are only 8 executors, each with about 4 cores.  Currently I'm running the experiment on an m3.xlarge, but if I can get past this I/O bottleneck it may make sense to move to an instance with more physical cores.

Comment: I do not have the code publicly available, but what we essentially did was -- within each task before entering the network intensive call we would call a central service who would keep track of how many other tasks are within the same block and if it is less than some k it will allow else ask this task to go for a busy spin for a sec and retry. And then when a task is done with the network call it will update the central service so. Admittedly not the most elegant thing, but we were able to reduce job time from 90 mins to under 50 mins.

Comment: After some more digging I discovered that using S3 native makes a huge difference.  I just changed the URI prefix to s3n://  and the performance for the job in question went from 2.5 minutes down to 21s.  So only a 3s penalty for accessing s3 vs hdfs, which is pretty reasonable.  Not sure if this will apply to your problem though as the docs I've seen so far indicate there is a file size limit of 5GB when using s3 native.

Comment: I just found [this](https://notes.mindprince.in/2014/08/01/difference-between-s3-block-and-s3-native-filesystem-on-hadoop.html) which says the file size limit was increased to 5TB in Hadoop 2.4.0

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the spark-csv package? There is a lot of optimization for reading csv and you can use mode=MALFORMED to drop bad lines you are trying to filter. You can read from s3 directly like this:

```
csv_rdf<- read.df(sqlContext,"s3n://xxxxx:xxxxx@foldername/file1.csv",source="com.databricks.spark.csv")
```

More details can be found here https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv

Comment: I had tried spark-csv in the past, but no difference in performance.  But thanks for the pointer on mode=MALFORMED.  I did not know about that mode, and could help simplify my code.  thanks